# How to run Pytest in Visual Studio Code on MacOS?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, macos-catalina

I am new here and just started studying engineering but I am having problems with my System (MacOS Catalina) and Visual Studio Code.

So I wrote some Generator-function

```
def gen(l:list)->Iterator[int]:
    for i in l:
        yield i

a = gen([1,2,3,4])
b = gen([1,4,9,16])

def chain(xs,ys: Iterator[int])->Iterator[int]:
    for x in xs:
        yield x
    for y in ys:
        yield y


def test_chain():
    assert list(chain(a,b)) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

And I am supposed to run Pytest on my Unittest, but when I run it (with writing pytest in the terminal), it searches for my tests for 10 sec and then gives me an "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" even though I allowed VSC in my settings to search through my documents.

Do I need to install pytest differently or call for pytest differently? I am quite desperate here and would appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How *exactly* are you running pytest? Please [edit] to show the commands in the terminal and if you are passing any config options.

Comment: @adrian.tgb -Please refer to the content of [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) to check the usage of the test.